# hide/show fields on chekbox check on symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

hia i have a form in symfony and i whant when i check on a chekbox to show and hide some values i didn't find a way to do it ive tried this but it's working not the way i want

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{


    $builder
        ->add('textAnnonce')
        ->add('cloturer')
        ->add('User')
        ->add('test', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'     => 'Ajouter Immobilier ?',
            'required'  => false, 
            'data' => false))

    ;

   //  if ($options['test'] == true)
     //   {
    $builder        
       ->add('Immobilier', new ImmobilierType() )      

        ;
    // }
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Colocation\ColocationBundle\Entity\OffreColocation',
      //  'test' => false
        ));
}
```

the thing is that i want to test in the value of

```
 ->add('test', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'     => 'Ajouter Immobilier ?',
            'required'  => false, 
            'data' => false))
```

Answer (score 0):

you either need to have javascript handle the hiding / showing of your field or make an ajax call to your controller when the checkbox is check and then insert the new form into the page.